# Macro to create Hyperlinks to specific files on same excel file folder

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, macros

I´m new on VBA coding on excel, and need your help. I have the following problem, for example:

1) On the folder I have the template.xlsx and few archives:

```
alpha.pdf
beta.pdf
delta.pdf
gamma.pdf
```

2) inside template.xlsx I have the columns:

```
PRICE   FILE     ADDRESS
1       alpha
1       beta
1       delta
1       gamma
...     ...     ...
```

3) I want to create a macro to set hyperlink on each cell on Column "B" to respective file on folder.

Can I do it with VBA? On the real excel file I have more than 1000 rows.

Comment: well there's a few questions that you need to answer. Are all the pdf's in the same folder? IF so this is super easy.

Comment: Yes, all files are in the same folder!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a macro for this - you can get the filepath information from the `CELL` function, then build a hyperlink.  Assuming that the file is in cell B2:

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(LEFT(CELL("filename",B2),FIND("[",CELL("filename",B2))-1),B2,".pdf"))
```